# Some good books to learn more about eigenvalue,eigenvectors of linear maps; spectral theory of linear operators and linear algebra over modules?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, reference-request, modules, spectral-theory

I finished master's with very reasonable background. I already did a course on Linear Algebra. Just want some books to go deeper than a introductory course. I want the books to be as comprehensive as possible. Also,it would be of much help if they have big set of problems and examples. Solutions are welcome but not needed. Thank You.

Comment: Have a look at "Advanced Linear Algebra" by Steven Roman.